# Conservative nature of electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, conservative-field

It's a straightforward question. Electrostatic force is conservative, but I've read that the electric field generated according to Faraday's law of induction is not. What's the difference between these two cases, which makes the latter non-conservative?

Answer (score 1):

The line integral of the induced electric field is not zero.
It can be shown that, for an induced electric field:
$$\oint \vec E \cdot \vec {\mathrm{d}l} = -\iint \frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}\cdot\vec {\mathrm{d}A}$$

where $\vec B$ is the magnetic field and $\vec E$ is the induced electric field.

As per Lenz's law induced emf $$\epsilon =- \frac{d\phi}{dt}$$ where $\phi$ is the magnetic flux.

$$\phi = \int \int \vec B \cdot \vec{\mathrm dA}$$

The induced emf(left hand side) represents the work done by the field.

Thr right hand side is the rate of change of flux through the area.

This is given by Faraday's law.

So the work done around a closed loop is not zero.

But the line integral of an electrostatic electric field in a closed loop amounts to zero.

Comment: I didn't understand the right hand side of the equation. I am not familiar with it. Could you explain this in another way?

Answer (score 0):

A field is conservative if it's "curl" is 0. That is, the field $\vec{E}$ is conservative if

$$\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$$

An important mathematical result is that the above equation is equivalent to the statement that there is a scalar potential field $V$ such that $\vec{E}$ is the gradient of $V$.

$$\vec{E} = \nabla V$$

[Actually, if there is *one* solution, there are an infinite number of solutions, because adding a constant to the scalar field V, and then taking the gradient will give an identical vector field.]

$$\nabla V = \nabla (V +k)$$

The characterization of conservative vector fields in terms of gradients is often easier to understand at first than the characterization in terms of curls. If we can represent some vector field as the gradient of some scalar field, then the vector field is conservative.

> wh[at] makes [an electric field induced by a time-varying magnetic field] non-conservative?

Simple. The curl of the induced electric field is not zero.

$$\nabla \times \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} \ne 0$$